# SQL query for GROUP BY, with COALESCE, LEAST, MIN

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, min, coalesce

I want to write an SQL query calling for several columns with a bit complicated conditions. I'm working on R Studio using RMySQL package. My server is MySQL.

The table looks like this.

```
organisation    Tour_ID             A           B           C           D  
Ikea                  a    2018-04-01  2018-05-07  2018-05-09  2018-05-01
Ikea                  a    2018-06-01  2018-05-03  2018-05-29          NA   
Ikea                  a    2018-04-02  2018-05-01  2018-07-08  2018-05-26 
Ikea                  b    2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26
Ikea                  b    2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26
Ikea                  b            NA  2018-05-05  2018-08-02  2018-06-01
Ikea                  c    2018-06-01  2018-05-07  2018-05-09  2018-05-01
Ikea                  c    2018-06-01  2018-05-03          NA          NA   
Ikea                  c    2018-08-02  2018-05-09  2018-07-08  2018-05-26
```

This is what I want to do:

1. filter the rows where `organisation = Ikea`
2. groupby by `Tour_ID` like this:

   ```
   organisation    Tour_ID             A           B           C           D  
   Ikea                  a    2018-04-01  2018-05-07  2018-05-09  2018-05-01
   Ikea                  a    2018-06-01  2018-05-03  2018-05-29          NA   
   Ikea                  a    2018-04-02  2018-05-01  2018-07-08  2018-05-26 


   Ikea                  b    2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26
   Ikea                  b    2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26
   Ikea                  b            NA  2018-05-05  2018-08-02  2018-06-01


   Ikea                  c    2018-06-01  2018-05-07  2018-05-09  2018-05-01
   Ikea                  c    2018-06-01  2018-05-03          NA          NA   
   Ikea                  c    2018-08-02  2018-05-09  2018-07-08  2018-05-26
   ```
3. in each group of `Tour_ID`, look at the earliest date in columns `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. If the earliest date among the four columns in the group is between `2018-05-01` and `2018-05-31`, return the entire group. If a row contains `NA` values, I want to ignore the `NA`s and see what's the earliest date among the rest of the values. For example, for the group of `Tour_ID = a`,  the earliest date is `2018-04-01` therefore it doesn't meet the criteria.

In conclusion, only the groups where `Tour_ID = b` and `Tour_ID = c` match the conditions. The result should be:

```
organisation    Tour_ID             A           B           C           D
Ikea                  b    2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26
Ikea                  b    2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26
Ikea                  b            NA  2018-05-05  2018-08-02  2018-06-01
Ikea                  c    2018-06-01  2018-05-07  2018-05-09  2018-05-01
Ikea                  c    2018-06-01  2018-05-03          NA          NA   
Ikea                  c    2018-08-02  2018-05-09  2018-07-08  2018-05-26
```

How should I write an SQL query?
Here is my attempt:

```
"SELECT t.* FROM myTable JOIN (SELECT organisation, Tour_ID 
                                                   FROM myTable
                                                   WHERE organisation LIKE 'Ikea' AND
                                                   GROUP BY organisation, Tour_ID
                                                   HAVING LEAST(COALESCE(MIN(A), '2119-01-01'), 
                                                                COALESCE(MIN(B), '2119-01-01'), 
                                                                COALESCE(MIN(C), '2119-01-01'), 
                                                                COALESCE(MIN(D), '2119-01-01')) >= '2018-05-01' AND
                                                          LEAST(COALESCE(MIN(A), '2119-01-01'), 
                                                                COALESCE(MIN(B), '2119-01-01'), 
                                                                COALESCE(MIN(C), '2119-01-01'), 
                                                                COALESCE(MIN(D), '2119-01-01')) < '2018-06-01'
                                                  ) tt
                                                  ON tt.Tour_ID = t.Tour_ID AND
                                                     tt.organisation = t.organisation"
```

But I don't think it's correctly choses `Tour_ID = c`, because of the usage of `COALESCE`.

For the group of `Tour_ID = c`, there is `NA` in the column `D`so `COALESCE(MIN(D), '2119-01-01')` returns `2119-01-01`. But it shouldn't, because the least value in the column `D` is `2018-05-01` and this has to be compared to the least values in column `A`, `B` and `C`. Indeed, `2018-05-01` in column `D` is the least value in the entire group so I think `COALESCE(MIN(D), '2119-01-01')` is wrong.

But I don't know what's the solution for this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are there only ever a,b,c,d columns?

Comment: there are 80 columns but here I only care about these four

Answer (score 1):

P.Salmon's solution assumes that when the lowest date in a whole organisation + Tour_ID is within the given time frame, that then needs to be displayed. 
When you want to display the group when either 1 line has a lowest value in A, B, C or D within the time frame, you need this:

```
SELECT myTable.*
FROM myTable 
JOIN (
   SELECT organisation, tour_id
   FROM myTable
   WHERE  
         LEAST(COALESCE(A, '2119-01-01'), COALESCE(B, '2119-01-01'), 
               COALESCE(C, '2119-01-01'), COALESCE(D, '2119-01-01'))
         BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31'
   GROUP BY organisation,tour_id
) s ON s.organisation = myTable.organisation AND s.tour_id = myTable.tour_id
WHERE myTable.organisation = 'ikea';
```

Comment: Cleaner and more accurate answer IMO, but should remain as a JOIN to only get those dates the person expected in result set.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Sorry I'm beginner at SQL, but where should I declare the name of the table `myTable`? Also, I think there is a syntax error(maybe missing `)` after `AND '2018-05-31'`? But I'm not sure...

Comment: The from and where clauses are the wrong way round.

Comment: This doesn't work at all even if you flip  from and where clauses

Comment: Changed the query to add the 'myTable' to it and fixed the FROM and WHERE error.

Answer (score 0):

I would use and if instead of coalesce and rearrange the code slightly

```
select t.*
from t 
join
(
select organisation,tour_id,
        min(
        least(if(a='na',date(now()),a),if(b='na',date(now()),b),if(c='na',date(now()),c),if(d='na',date(now()),d))
        ) mindt
from t
group by organisation,tour_id
) s on s.organisation = t.organisation and s.tour_id = t.tour_id
where t.organisation = 'ikea' and s.mindt between '2018-05-01' and '2018-05-31';

+----+--------------+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| id | organisation | Tour_ID | A          | B          | C          | D          |
+----+--------------+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  4 | Ikea         | b       | 2018-06-02 | 2018-05-01 | NA         | 2018-05-26 |
|  5 | Ikea         | b       | 2018-06-02 | 2018-05-01 | NA         | 2018-05-26 |
|  6 | Ikea         | b       | NA         | 2018-05-05 | 2018-08-02 | 2018-06-01 |
|  7 | Ikea         | c       | 2018-06-01 | 2018-05-07 | 2018-05-09 | 2018-05-01 |
|  8 | Ikea         | c       | 2018-06-01 | 2018-05-03 | NA         | NA         |
|  9 | Ikea         | c       | 2018-08-02 | 2018-05-09 | 2018-07-08 | 2018-05-26 |
+----+--------------+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this case where should I declare the name of the table `myTable`?

Comment: I replaced `t` with `myTable` but 0 rows are returned... Do you know why?

Comment: where should I put `myTable`?

Comment: can somebody explain why this answer doesn't contain `myTable`? how is it possible to make a query without mentioning the name of the table?

Comment: I have chosen to call the table t

Comment: Ok thank you. then I rewrote the second line of your query like `select t.* from myTable t`, but now it says `Error Code: 1146. Table 'myTable.t' doesn't exist.` I really don't get how your query works. Could you please explain?

Comment: If your table is called my table then change the 2 occurrences of from table with from mytable as t and research table alias